# how to configure apache mod_rewrite to redirect to non-www version with two exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, redirect

I'd like to redirect incoming requests to our `https://` non-www version of the site using a 301 redirect. It is required to exclude two subdomains specifically (`webmin.domain.com` and `newsletter.domain.com`)

This is what I have so far

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^(newsletter|webmin)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem with the above is, that it creates an infinite loop because it seems that the RewriteCond matches the non-www version of the URL.

How can I extend this rewrite rule properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!newsletter|webmin)[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: loaded this rule into the apache conf and testet for https://test.domain.com/targetDirectory. The rule does not yet redirect to https://domain.com/targetDirectory

Comment: japp! cleared browser cache and just tried again to be sure ;-)

Comment: @Jabb `HTTPS_HOST` is not a real variable. I didn't notice that before :/